# Have Perforce mail an arbitrary email address upon submit?

Tags: perforce

With perforce, a user can get email notifications of changes to a particular file or directory by specifying it in the `Reviews` field of the user record (more details in the [Perforce documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/user.html)).

However, I would like to have email notifications sent to a team mailing list, which is of course not a perforce user.  One kludgy way of accomplishing this would be to have a team member put the mailing list in for his email address, while another would be to create a user account for the mailing list (would this require another license?).  Surely there has to be better way, though.

Comment: I'd add that the p4 review daemon does not come pre-installed. You have to download it and install it as a daemon on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use a user review field, you are entitled to a free "background user" license that might fit your needs (this way, none of your "real" users would need to change their email address):

> A "background user" is a Perforce user
>   account that is used solely for
>   automated tasks, such as triggers and
>   daemons. Perforce customers with
>   current licenses can have an
>   additional user added to their license
>   file, free of charge, on request.
>   Contact Perforce support for more
>   information.

Or, you could look into doing what you need with some sort of [p4 trigger](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html).

Answer (score 2):

The perforce Review daemon is just a python script available [here](http://public.perforce.com/public/perforce/utils/reviewd/p4review.py) that runs on the server   ( or any machine for that matter ) and polls check-ins on a regular interval and then mails users based on what they have set in the review field of their clientspec.
There's no reason why you can't modify it and extend it to do whatever you want including mailing a team mailing list if you want instead.
I've always rolled my own review daemon ( using the vanilla daemon as a starting point )

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answers (in 2014).

There are now more than one way to do it:

- [p4review.py](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/public/perforce/utils/reviewd/p4review.py) - the original (example) script.
- [p4review2.py](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/public/perforce/utils/reviewd/p4review2.py) - a rewrite of p4review.py with more [features and options](http://wiki.workshop.perforce.com/wiki/P4Review2).
- [p4notifyd.pl](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/public/perforce/utils/reviewd/p4notifyd.pl) - a Perl version.
- [Perforce Swarm](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/swarm) - a web-based code review system with email notification support built-in.